# How to recive pending transaction hash?

Tags: javascript, web3js

I need get pending tx hash for display this hash to user, when user send contract method. How can this be implemented?

```
await contract.methods.deposit().send({ from: this.props.accounts[0], value:amount})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```
    myContract.methods.myMethod(123).send({from: 
   '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'})
    .on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
        ...
    })
```